# GMail access in Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, gmail, gdata, gmail-imap, gmail-pop

I am creating a widget based application in which I need to create a widget for GMail. This application uses xulrunner based technology stack. Major features required in this widget are:
1. List of mails
2. Read/Delete/Mark/Reply/Compose a mail.

I have come across the Google's GData API which is available for all major Google products like Blogs,Calendar,YouTube etc but not for GMail. Another way I found is to use unofficial GMail Mobile API [here](http://codeplusplus.blogspot.com/2007/07/mobile-gmail-api.html).

Does anybody have any other good way of doing this? Particularly I would really like to know about accessing GMail via IMAP/POP3.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found this in under 1 minute of searching. http://code.google.com/intl/iw-IL/apis/gmail/imap/

This is the Google IMAP API site, it explains everything you need.

Comment: that article does not specify how to use it with Javascript or Mozilla Technology stack. I need that information. please let me know if i have missed something on that site.